# Does a JPEG stream also contain the total length between FFD8 to FFD9?

Tags: mjpeg

I'm trying to implement a very simple Motion JPEG player... and I'm wondering whether a JPEG also contains somewhere the total length (from FFD8 to FFD9) so that I can read the whole frame in one shot without having to parse the data for a FFD9 sequence. Thanks.